# Android-Relative Layout inside Scroll View with fixed header and footer

Tags: android, android-layout, height, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I want a page which has a static header and footer with scrollable content inside. This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sendfunds" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollablContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerView" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:text="Balance"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="8pt"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:text="WHO ARE YOU SENDING MONEY TO?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:text="Recipient Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Recipient Email"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                android:text="HOW MUCH DO YOU WANT TO SEND?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:text="Amount"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="Wallet Cat."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:text="Pay Ref."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:text="Detail Ref."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
                android:text="Date of Birth"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
                android:text="Submit" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/wallet_ic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:src="@drawable/send_ic_hover" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/upload_ic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/history1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/more" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

With this I have the static header and footer but some of the scrollable content is missing. I tried increasing the height of the `ScrollView` and layout and `fillViewport=true` but no luck. How should I increase the height of the middle layout?

Comment: Why dont you use a ListView with a header and footer?

Comment: I'm quite sure the header, the middle layout (`ScrollView`) and the footer are configured right. So please check again all children views inside the `RelativeLayout`, which is inside the middle `ScrollView`. I think the problem came from there.

Comment: Sir I dont quite seem to follow you.I am new in android.Please can u elaborate a bit further.

Comment: @Antrromet I dont know how to get values from listview...please can u give me some example

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by using a **LinearLayout** container instead of **RelativeLayout** container.

The container should have 3 children: Header, Content, and Footer. Where the Content's height is set to fill the remaining space. You can do that by using the weight attribute:

```
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

Use this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sendfunds" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollablContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <!-- Your Content -->                

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/wallet_ic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:src="@drawable/send_ic_hover" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/upload_ic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/history1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/more" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice that using

```
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true
```

is meaningless within **LinearLayout**. So this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sendfunds" />
</LinearLayout>
```

is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:orientation=”vertical” >

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sendfunds" />  

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollablContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=1
>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Balance"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="WHO ARE YOU SENDING MONEY TO?"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="Recipient Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Recipient Email"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="HOW MUCH DO YOU WANT TO SEND?"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Wallet Cat."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="Pay Ref."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:text="Detail Ref."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="Date of Birth"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Submit" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/wallet_ic" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
      android:src="@drawable/send_ic_hover" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
      android:src="@drawable/upload_ic" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
      android:src="@drawable/history1" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView5"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
      android:src="@drawable/more" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout  >
```

Comment: With this code I a getting this error"”vertical”" in attribute "orientation" is not a valid value

Comment: I corrected the vertical error but it did not change anything...same thing occured

Answer (score 0):

try this layout with small change in your layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sendfunds" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/wallet_ic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:src="@drawable/send_ic_hover" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/upload_ic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/history1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/more" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollablContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerView" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:text="Balance"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="8pt"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:text="WHO ARE YOU SENDING MONEY TO?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:text="Recipient Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Recipient Email"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                android:text="HOW MUCH DO YOU WANT TO SEND?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:text="Amount"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="Wallet Cat."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:text="Pay Ref."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:text="Detail Ref."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
                android:text="Date of Birth"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
                android:text="Submit" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```